# Determine adjacent <li> inside a nested HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a **nested list**. One element inside that list contains a class called *"special"*. This particular node can be present anywhere within the nested list. E.g.,

```
<ul id="mylist">
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>
    <ul>
        <li>3</li>
        <li class="special">4</li>
        <li>
           <ul>
              <li>5</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

When I click a button, I need to apply two classes, say "up" and "down" to the nodes above and below the special node. So in the case of above example, the resulting list should look like this:

```
<ul id="mylist">
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>
    <ul>
        <li class="up">3</li>
        <li class="special">4</li>
        <li>
           <ul>
              <li class="down">5</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, since my list is a nested list and the special `<li>` node can be present at any position, hence the "up" and "down" `<li>` may be required to be placed inside some other `<ul>` as well.

**MY IDEA**

1. My initial idea was to do DOM traversing but it soon became very complicated.
2. Next I thought I will create an array of all `<li>` inside my list (`$("#mylist").find ("li")`), then find out which of these `<li>` has "special" class (`hasClass("special")`) and once I know that array index where "special" occurs, i will do +1, -1 to get the lower and upper nodes. But I don't know how to do this..

Comment: What if `.special` is the first (or last) child?

Comment: If it is first, then only '.down' will be applied. Similarly, if it is last then only '.up' will be applied

Comment: There 3 more <li> elements 'above' the special node in your sample code. Why isn't 'up' class applied to these nodes?

Comment: Because it should be applied to the *adjacent* `li` nodes, i.e. the *immediate* upper or lower `li` nodes

Comment: Is the `.down` `li` really *adjacent* to `.special` or is it's ancestor? Please clarify?

Comment: `.down` is *adjacent* to `.special` in the sense that when you see the markup on screen the node 4 and 5 are adjacent (although they are not adjacent `li` as they remain inside two different `ul`)

Comment: Then you're going to need a special function to traverse the DOM to look for the *next rendered* or *prev rendered* `li` element. Check out my answer.

Comment: *Welcome to StackOverflow!* Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to figure out which `li` has `.special`. From there, you can use your idea #2:

```
var lis = $("#mylist").find ("li");
lis.eq(lis.index('.special')-1).addClass('up');
lis.eq(lis.index('.special')+1).addClass('down');
```

Comment: Never knew about `index()`... it did what I wanted to do with my 2nd idea. Neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Considering *adjacent* in your case has a special meaning, I have written a small plugin that takes that *special* definition into account. Would this represent accurately what you're looking for?

```js
$.fn.adjacent = function(options) {
  var df = $.extend({dir: 'up'}, options);
  return this.each(function() {
    var elem = df.dir === 'up' ? $(this).prev() : $(this).next();
    while( $('li', elem).length ) {
      elem = df.dir === 'up' ? $('li', elem).last() : $('li', elem).first();
    }
    elem.addClass(df.dir);
  });
};

$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('#mylist li.special')
    .adjacent()
    .adjacent({dir:'down'});
});
```

```css
.up {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
.down {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mylist">
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>
    <ul>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>3.1</li>
            <li>3.2</li>
            <li>3.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="special">4</li>
        <li>
           <ul>
              <li>
                <ul>
                  <li>4.1</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>5</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>6</li>
</ul>

<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Yes, it does represent what I am looking for. In fact, conceptually this approach is what I was trying to do in the beginning but could not succeed. Thanks.

Comment: Since I have to choose any one answer, I have chosen @Scimonster reply as answer for brevity.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help, any time. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're really asking is *"How do I get the nodes containing the preceding and the following number in an ordered tree graph?"* You're just using `<ul>` and `<li>` tags in HTML DOM as non-terminal and terminal nodes respectively. The solution is proper tree traversal.

```
function isBranch (node) {
    return node.is('ul');
}
function isList (node) {
    return node.is('li');
}
function getPrevious (node) {
    while (node.length && !node.previous().length) {
        node = node.parent();
    }
    while (isBranch(node) && !isLeaf(node)) {
        node = node.children().last();
    }
    return isLeaf(node) ? node : $();
}
function getNext (node) {
    while (node.length && !node.next().length) {
        node = node.parent();
    }
    while (isBranch(node) && !isLeaf(node)) {
        node = node.children().first();
    }
    return isLeaf(node) ? node : $();
}

function markPreviousAndNext (node) {
    getPrevious(node).addClass('up');
    getNext(node).addClass('down');
}

markPreviousAndNext($('#mylist .special'));
```

---

Please take your time and try to frame your question (and its title) better, so that the answer may help future searchers. I can't really think up a really appropriate title at short notice.